# Write Sequence in Sigma notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been asked to write the following two sequences in $\sum$ notation.

1. $1-2+4-8+16-32$
2. $1*3-2*5+3*7-4*9+5*11$

My answers were as follows:

1. $\sum_{1}^6 2^{r-1}(-1)^{r-1}$
2. $\sum_{1}^5 r(-1)^{r-1}(2r+1)$

However, the answer book gave the following answers:

1. $\sum_{1}^6 (-1)^{r+1}2^{r-1}$
2. $\sum_{1}^5 (-1)^{r+1}r(2r+1)$

Apart from the fact that the ordering of the terms is different, they use $(-1)^{r+1}$, rather than $(-1)^{r-1}$.

I think that $(-1)^0 = 1$, ergo $(-1)^{r-1}$ is also an acceptable solution.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours are correct because $$(-1)^{r-1}=(-1)^{r-1}\cdot 1=(-1)^{r-1}\cdot(-1)^2=(-1)^{(r-1)+2}=(-1)^{r+1}.$$

Comment: Oh yeah, nice, thanks!